# Syntax Error ncurses + python3

Tags: python

I've been trying to make my first program in Python 3 with Ncurses and I'm stuck trying to figure out this syntax error. I'm trying to build the ncurses menu topbar menu and I'm getting the following error;

```
s.refresh()  c = s.getch()  
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've been trying learn off from here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python6/#h3 but I cannot figure out why I'm getting syntax error with this. It happens with both `Python 3.4.0` and `Python 2.7.6` when I test it out. Also the menu's aren't rendering when I do go to test it out. I get nothing displaying at all. I'm just trying to make a simple program with very basic functions, nothing too special.

The problem is this piece of ncurses code when I try to add it to my own python script

```
def file_func():
    s = curses.newwin(5,10,2,1)
    s.box()
    s.addstr(1,2, "I", hotkey_attr)
    s.addstr(1,3, "nput", menu_attr)
    s.addstr(2,2, "O", hotkey_attr)
    s.addstr(2,3, "utput", menu_attr)
    s.addstr(3,2, "T", hotkey_attr)
    s.addstr(3,3, "ype", menu_attr)
    s.addstr(1,2, "", hotkey_attr)
    s.refresh()  c = s.getch()  
    if c in (ord('I'), ord('i'), curses.KEY_ENTER, 10):
        curses.echo()
        s.erase()
        screen.addstr(5,33, " "*43, curses.A_UNDERLINE)
        cfg_dict['source'] = screen.getstr(5,33)
        curses.noecho()
    else:
        curses.beep()
        s.erase()
    return CONTINUE
```

Here's what the current output looks like before trying to add the menu, before I got syntax error on the above code example at `s.refresh() c = s.getch()` line.

[image: preview example of output before trying to add menu]
The is first time trying something like this in Python3 and Ncurses, I wanted to give it a go to see what I can do to make a simple functional program. ALso I'm not too sure how to customize the output more with Ncurses, I did want to change the colors and put a background fill to the boxed window it created, but not too sure on that, the tutorials I've read don't make it too clear on how to implement this into Python. Not too sure if I can just bundle it all into one script which is the main idea approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
s.refresh()  c = s.getch()
```

You cannot place an assignment statement on the same line as a function call like you are doing.  You need to use a semicolon to separate the lines:

```
s.refresh(); c = s.getch()
#          ^
```

Note however that many Python programmers find the use of semicolons inelegant.  It would be better to just use two lines:

```
s.refresh()
c = s.getch()
```

Comment: ahh okay I see what was wrong now. But now I'm getting this ```SyntaxError: 'return' outside function``` on ```return CONTINUE``` I checked my indentation and it's all been consistent with 4 space indentation. Any idea why it's complaining?

Comment: That error can only be generated if a return-statement is written outside of a function.  If you are confident that you are not mixing tabs and spaces (that is a huge source of these types of errors), then you should scan your source file for every occurrence of `return`.  One or more of them are out of place.  Usually, this is done by pressing Ctrl+F and then entering what you want to find.

Comment: I checked through every line carefully and it's all spaces, no tabs mixed in with it, but the error still happens.

Comment: I think the indentation of the if-statement inside your `file_func` function was wrong.  I have edited your question to fix this (using 4 spaces as you said).  Replace the `file_func` in your source file with the fixed one in your question.  It should solve your problem.